# How to find an object in a certain radius with a certain tag near a certain point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to find an object with the tag "block" in a certain radius from the point. How can this be done?

I tried to look for an object whose coordinates are less than the coordinates of the point to which the radius is added, but it didn't work and the engine just froze dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) can help you with that. It gives you a list of colliders that were hit by the defined sphere, you can loop over them and compare the tags.

Overlapsphere could also be restricted to work on specific layers (using the layermask), which may help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the problem, this script helps to search for components within a radius, as well as the nearest and farthest of them https://github.com/Delmas237/VersatileUnityTools/tree/main/ComponentSearcher

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34882575)